# How to resize page to fit drawing contents in Open office/Libre Office Draw

Tags: java, api, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I am programmatically drawing a flowchart in open office draw by means of Java UNO Runtime Reference api.After I have drawn the flowchart I want to resize the page according to the area aquired by the contents drawn.I have noticed that Microsoft Visio has a property called "size to fit drawing contents" in its "page setup" which does this when I draw flowchart in Visio.Pls suggest how can I do the same thing in Open office/Libre Office Draw.

Comment: Even in Inkscape (GPL free software) you have under *Properties* the possibility *Resize page to content*

Comment: This bug seems fitting https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81118

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it manually:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything.
2. Under `Format`>`Position and Size` you can see the exact size of the selection. It's helpful to copy the value of Width and Height to an editor (or a piece of paper). Click <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.
3. Open `Format`>`Page`: Set Width and Height according to the size of the selection. Set all Margins to zero. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
4. Open `Format`>`Position and Size` again: Set both Position X an Position Y to zero. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Well, it's not so fast, but works.

Comment: One thing to note: sometimes the size does not account for the width of the line. For example, if you create a circle with a thick line, then the calculated width might cutoff the edges. You'll have to adjust. This sometimes happens when you export a select shape too.